# CSS Hover bug in review close votes

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I just hit 3000rep and noticed that if you are scrolled down a little bit on the Review Close Votes page, and select "Close" you get this incorrect hovering:

It is covering up a couple options.

http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/5058/2b20aee8f7a742c89a21a19.png

Not sure how to fix it, because i didnt dive into the HTML and stuff.

This is reproducable while scrolled partially down the page and clicking "Close" in Google Chrome version 23.0.1271.64 m

It stays behind the red pop-up, until the page is scrolled far enough down that the "Should this question be closed" box starts to move with the page, at which point it comes on top.

p.s: I realize that i can just hit "less" , however the "Should this question be closed..." would still be on top, and it is still incorrect behavior.

Comment: I can confirm this issue - just tested for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have added a z-index to that dialog.  It should be fixed in the next build.